# PhpStorm replace with js Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, phpstorm, webstorm

I have:

```
const abc = require('abc');
const def = require('de-f');

const ght = require('ght');
```

And I need to change it with <kbd>Ctrl + R</kbd> (replace option) in PhpStorm to:

```
import abc from 'abc';
import def from 'de-f';
```

and have the same:

```
const ght = require('gth');
```

So I came with idea to write in first input something like this:

```
const\s([ad])
```

Which catches `const` + space + first letter(`a` and `d`) in `abc` and `def`.
But how to catch whole word(`abc` and `def`) + `=` symbol and next `require`?

Comment: [`^\s*const\s([ad]\w+)\s*=\s*require\((.*?)\);$`](https://regex101.com/r/jlFWeB/2)

Comment: Thank you very much! You gave me ideas and I did `const (\w+) = require\(.([\w-]+).\);` and it worked well!

Answer (score 0):

i guess you can try to match this regex pattern:

```
.*\s(\w+)\s=\s.*\('(.*)\'\);
```

and replace by this:

```
import $1 from '$2';
```